# Passing a JavaScript variable using AJAX to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to pass a JavaScript variable from `index.php` to `response.php`, but no output is coming. I am new in JavaScript and AJAX... Please let me know if something is missing:

**index.php**:

```
var var_data = "Hello World";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sub').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'response.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**response.php**:

```
$test = $_GET['var_PHP_data'];
echo "variable is : .$test";
```

Comment: Check the network tab & console. Also post the HTML.

Comment: have you tried to alert the response "data".

Comment: is `response.php` in the same directory as `index.php`?

Comment: Its working what is the is problem ?

Comment: you forgot your result html element `<p id="result"></p>`

Comment: I am using this **<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub"/>** to submit and its not redirecting to response.php..and not printing the echo variable.

Comment: @Raj try to change type="button" instead of type="submit" see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this HTML for your `index.php` page:

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var var_data = "Hello World";
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#sub').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'response.php',
               type: 'GET',
               data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },
               success: function(data) {
                 $('#result').html(data);
               },
               error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  //case error
                }
             });
          });
      }); 
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub"/>
     <p id="result"></p>
   </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: One more doubt.. I want to use **window.open('response.php',height='+h+',width='+w+', value='result');** in url so that response page will open as separate page...How I can do that... Please help....and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Write it as:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'response.php?var_PHP_data='+var_data,
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(data) { 
        //success 
       $('#result').html(data);
   }
})
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
<script>
var var_data = "Hello World";
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sub').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'response.php?var_PHP_data='+var_data,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#result').html(data)
}
});
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub"/>
</body>
</html>

Comment: you forgot your result html element `<p id="result"></p>`

Comment: The first script  tag is not closed:<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax then it should be

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub"/>
```

not

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub"/>
```

It will create problem if you use html code like this

```
<form action="" type="get">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub"/> </body> </html>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with the jquery libray, I used this link and its working fine now.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```